# Permissions as in django

Tags: django, scala, authentication, playframework, authorization

Is it possible to implement similar decorator (from django) in playframework?

```
@permission_required('polls.can_vote')
def my_view(request):
   return HttpResponse('Ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the official documentation of Play, than they have a few [examples for handling Security](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaSecurity).

Quickly adapting the example code to your needs:

```
def permissionNeeded(group: String)(f: User=> Request[AnyContent] => Result) = withAuth { username => implicit request =>
  UserDao.findOneByUsername(username).flatMap { user =>
    PermissionDao.hasPermission(user, group).map {
      permissionedUser => f(permissionedUser)(request)
    }
  }.getOrElse(onUnauthorized(request))
}
```

An example controller method would look like this:

```
def user() = permissionNeeded("polls.can_vote") { user => implicit request =>
  val username = user.username
  Ok(html.user(user))
}
```

If you would like to use annotations, then you'll have to look into [AspectJ and Scala](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2013/08/07/aspectj-with-akka-scala/).